# Mulesoft Salesforce Query says CareprogramEnrolleeId field does not exist

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

Trying to Query CareProgramEnrolleeId field from ProductRequest in salesforce using the mulesoft salesforce query connector. Getting an error saying the field does not exist but it does. Have checked permissions and everything looks good there. Using the same account that we are using for the mule integration I can query that field in dev console.

Query is : SELECT CareProgramEnrolleeId From ProductRequest

Error received: `Select CareProgramEnrolleeId From ProductRequest ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:8 No such column 'CareProgramEnrolleeId' on entity 'ProductRequest'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."`

Comment: Please provide details for reproduction, query, error from the logs. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to improve your question.

Comment: Check if the account that your mule code is using has permission to query that field. I have seen this error when enough permission is not provided. This might be the issue here too

Comment: @HarshankBansal that suggestion should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I checked and made sure the permissions were set up correctly.

Comment: @Trace Do you have access to developer console, if yes, are you able to execute the query in the salesforce developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Mulesoft API version it was using for salesforce needed to be updated to 49.0 or above. Issue is now resolved